# StatementInvalid Rails Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got the following query that works:

```
jobs = current_location.jobs.includes(:customer).all.where(complete: complete)
```

However, when I add a where clause to query the first name of the customer table, I get an error.

```
jobs = current_location.jobs.includes(:customer).all.where(complete: complete).where("customers.fist_name = ?", "Bob")
```

Here is the error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "customers"
LINE 1: ...bs"."complete" = $2 AND "jobs"."status" = $3 AND (customers....
                                                         ^
: SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs" INNER JOIN "jobs_users" ON "jobs"."id" = "jobs_users"."job_id" WHERE "jobs_users"."user_id" = $1 AND "jobs"."complete" = $2 AND "jobs"."status" = $3 AND (customers.last_name = 'Bob') ORDER BY "jobs"."start" DESC LIMIT $4 OFFSET $5
```

The current_location method:

```
def current_location
    return current_user.locations.find_by(id: cookies[:current_location])
end
```

Location Model

```
has_many :jobs
has_and_belongs_to_many :customers
```

Job Model

```
belongs_to :location
belongs_to :customer
```

Customer Model

```
has_many :jobs
has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Is `Job` the join table between `Customer` and `Location`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`includes` will only join the table if you set a reference to the association.

When using `includes` you ensure a reference to the association in 2 fashions:

- You can use the `references` method this will join the table whether or not there are any query conditions (If you MUST use raw SQL as shown in your question then this is the method you would need to use)  e.g.

  ```
  current_location.jobs
    .includes(:customer)
    .references(:customer)
  ```
- Or you can use the hash finder version of `where`: (Please note that when using an associative reference in the where clause you must reference the table name, in this case `customers` and not the association name `customer`)

  ```
  current_location.jobs
    .includes(:customer)
    .where(customers: {first_name: "Bob" })
  ```

Both of these will eager load the `customer` for the `jobs` referenced.

The first option (`references`) will OUTER JOIN the `customers` table so that all the jobs are loaded even if they have no customers as long as no query conditions reference the `customers` table.

The second option (using `where`) will OUTER JOIN the customers table but given the query parameter against the customers table it will act very much like an INNER JOIN.

If you only need to search the `jobs` based on `customer` information then `joins` is a better choice as this will create an INNER JOIN with the customers table but will not try to load any of the customer data in the query e.g.

```
current_location.jobs.joins(:customer).where(customers: {first_name: "Bob" })
```

`joins` will always include the associated table regardless of a reference in the query.

*Sidenote:* the `all` in both your queries is completely unnecessary

Comment: This worked. One thing that I don't quite understand is I have another almost identical query `jobs = Job.includes(:customer, :location, :users).where(location_id: current_location.id).where(users: {id: user.id}).where(complete: complete)` that works without using `references`. The only difference is that the query references a user and no joins to customer are made. Would this still fall inline with your answer?

Comment: @CannonMoyer yes the "customers" table will not be included in that query because there are no references to it nor would "locations" for that matter. Assuming `Job` has some direct association with `user`. If however the `user` association is `through` another association the needed tables would be joined accordingly so that the reference to `users` in your `where` were made valid. Also your `where` statements need not be broken up e.g. `where( complete: complete, location_id: current_location.id, users: {id: user.id})` would be the same as what you have

Answer (score 1):

`includes(:customer)` does not necessarily join the customers table into the SQL query. You need to use `joins(:customer)` to force Rails to join the `customers` table into the SQL query and make it available to query conditions.

```
jobs = current_location.jobs
                       .joins(:customer)
                       .includes(:customer)
                       .where(complete: complete)
                       .where(customers: { first_name: 'Bob' })
```